# почему оно выводит пустой массив?

Tags: javascript

Получить массив только уникальных значений с помощью reduce
[1, 9, 0, 1, 5, 9, 1, 6] -> [1, 9, 0, 5, 6]

```js
let arr = [1, 9, 0, 1, 5, 9, 1, 6];

let newArr = arr.reduce((acc, value, i) => {
  acc.push(value);
  let length = acc.length - 1;
  
  arr.forEach(value2 => {
    if (acc[length] === value2) {
      acc.pop();
    }
  })
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Что значит "ломается"?

Comment: value и value переименуй к второй value на value2

Comment: выводит пустой массив

Comment: Вы же формируете второй массив из элементов первого. Как минимум один раз элементы второго  массива будут встречаться в первом. И когда они встречаются, вы их удаляете сразу после добавления, поэтому массив всегда будет пустым.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty а break поможет?

Comment: Вам стоит уточнить необходимые условия. Есть способы сделать это проще. Вам обязательно использовать или не использовать какие-то определённые средства?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для тех, кто захочет найти уникальные значения правильно:

```js
const arr = [1, 9, 0, 1, 5, 9, 1, 6];

console.log([...new Set(arr)]);
console.log(Array.from(new Set(arr)));
```

Для автора:
Что-то вы слишком усложнили. `reduce` проходится по всех элементах, поэтому просто смотрим, есть ли текущий элемент в промежуточном списке `acc` с помощью `indexOf`. Если есть, то просто пропускаем. Если нет - добавляем.

```js
const arr = [1, 9, 0, 1, 5, 9, 1, 6];
const newArr = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (acc.indexOf(cur) === -1) {
    return acc.push(cur), acc;
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newArr);
```

Однострочный вариант:

```js
const arr = [1, 9, 0, 1, 5, 9, 1, 6];
console.log(arr.reduce((a,c)=>a.indexOf(c)===-1?(a.push(c),a):a,[]));
```